can not find the correct model space when using LibreDWG
When I use libredwg to read files, I find that the modelspace of some files can be read normally, but some cannot be read normally.
In normal cases, the modelspace read should be an insert header, but in abnormal cases, the modelspace read is a line or other entity, which makes it impossible to effectively obtain the relationship between all entities in the file.
I have tried the following methods:

I used the dwg_model_space_ref method and the dwg_model_space_object method, but I could not get the correct model space entry for some files. What is puzzling is that in the source code of the dwg_model_space_object method, when the model space entry in the file cannot be determined, the first insert header that can be obtained is returned, which will cause an error.
All entity objects are read out, and the tree structure of the model space is assembled by myself according to the owner information in them, but there are still many owners that are not read correctly, and the final result is scattered and incomplete.
My request is, when the correct model space entry in the file cannot be confirmed, is there a way to correctly read the data in the file so that I can get the correct hierarchical relationship?

